# Kill process parents in php

Tags: php, kill, kill-process, sigkill

I'm trying to stop a process by killing it, but to avoid the process zombies I must kill the ppid before killing the pid, here is my code to kill the pid :

```
$descriptorspec = array(array("pipe", "r"), array("pipe", "w"), array("pipe", "a"));
        $process = proc_open("MyProcessCommand", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
        $status = proc_get_status($process);
        $pid = $status['pid'];//Get the process id
```

{..}

```
$descriptorspec = array(array("pipe", "r"), array("pipe", "w"), array("pipe", "a"));
        proc_open("exec kill -9 $pid", $descriptorspec, $pipes); // killing the pid
        return new JsonResponse('Process Stopped');
```

So, I tried this one to get the ppid, but it seems not working well :

```
$descriptorspec = array(array("pipe", "r"), array("pipe", "w"), array("pipe", "a"));
            $process = proc_open("MyProcessCommand", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
            $status = proc_get_status($process);
            $pid = $status['pid'];//Get the process id
```

{..}

```
    $descriptorspec = array(array("pipe", "r"), array("pipe", "w"), array("pipe", "a"));

$ppid = proc_open("exec ps -o ppid= $pid", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

         proc_open("exec kill -9 $ppid", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
         proc_open("exec kill -9 $pid", $descriptorspec, $pipes); // killing the pid
                return new JsonResponse('Process Stopped');
```

Is there any other way to get the ppid? or to kill the process without leaving any zombie process?

Comment: `proc_open()` launches a shell and passes its first argument to the shell to be launched as a new process. The shell waits for the termination of the launched process and exits. Are you sure if you kill the process it becomes a zombie? It is not the regular behaviour of shells to ignore the termination of their children.

Comment: yes it does, look at this result of `ps axf` :

 `8217 ?        S      0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
 8437 ?        Z      0:00  |   \_ [php] <defunct>
 8221 ?        S      0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
 8338 ?        Z      0:00  |   \_ [php] <defunct>
 8290 ?        S      0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this,it will work

```
    $ppid=shell_exec("ps -o ppid= $pid");
    $int = (int)$ppid;
    var_dump($int);
    shell_exec("exec kill -9 $ppid");
    usleep(300);
    shell_exec("exec kill -9 $pid");
```